# Errors when changing level names in a factor

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I'm trying to rename the levels in a factor. I have a level "Very long text that needs to be shortened." and want to change its name to "Levelname". However, when I try:

`levels(df$varname) ["Very long text that needs to be shortened."] <- "Levelname"`

All that happens is that level `Levelname` that only has missing values is generated while `Very long text...` level continues to exist.

I can still rename the level using

`levels(df$varname) [1] <- "Levelname`

But would rather avoid it in case level numbers somehow change when I rerun the code. (I don't know if that would ever actually happen, but better safe than sorry.)

How can I rename the level and make sure the right level has its name changed?

Comment: Try `levels(df$varname)[levels(df$varname)=="Very long text that needs to be shortened."] <- "Levelname"`

Comment: Confirming this works (as does the code suggested by Melissa Key). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the levels aren't named, so you can't reference them that way.  If you want a safe way to manipulate factor levels, look at the `forcats` package (part of `tidyverse`).  That has the function `fct_recode` which will do what you want.

```
library(forcats)
df$varname <- fct_recode(df$varname, Levelname = "Very long text that needs to be shortened")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code(just an example):

```
y <- gl(2, 4, 8)
levels(y) <- c("low", "high")
y
```

output:

```
[1] low  low  low  low  high high high high
Levels: low high
```

Change *low* level to *medium*:

```
levels(y)[levels(y) == "low"] <- "medium"
y
```

output:

```
[1] medium medium medium medium high   high   high   high  
Levels: medium high
```